# ion-autocomplete in a IonicModal

Tags: ionic-framework, autocomplete

I would like to display the ion-autocomplete from guylabs within a IonicModal because the opening of the ion-autocomplete modal it to brutal.

When looking at their code, the div container goes from
`display:none` to `display:block` which makes it appear all of a sudden.

So I wanted to wrap it within a IonicModal but I am having a really hard time as I don't really know how to proceed.

I wrote the following code in codepen: [ion-autocomplete in IonicModal](http://codepen.io/mastronaut/pen/KaOeMw)

But the ion-autocomplete still appears all of a sudden and in front of my IonicModal.

Anyone already managed to wrap it in a IonicModal or even just change the animation ?